# MongoError: Invalid Operation, no operations specified Bulk.execute()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bulk

Everyone is saying that this Error means I am trying to Insert an Empty Array.
But how can i find this Empty Array in my code and fix it?

```html
const bulk = inspirations.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

  converter.fromFile(file)
    .on('json', async (obj) => {
      addToBulk(obj, bulk);
    })
    .on('done', async () => {
      console.log(`Finished reading: ${file}`);
      await Promise.all(promises);

   console.log(`Executing`);
   
      await   bulk.execute() ;
```

This is what get in the CLI :

- Connected successfully to server
- Connected successfully to db
- Finished reading File
- Executing

> (node:6836) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Invalid
>   Operation, no operations specified

Comment: Add some logging to your `addToBulk` method to see if it's doing what you expect.

Comment: After doing that i found that the file i'm importing is not being red the way i want to,
thanks !